# How do you constantly refresh a react component every certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This question relates a lot with loading and fetching. So I have this react components that loads comments from an API

```
function App (){

    const [com, setCom] = useState([])

    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)


    useEffect(() =>{

        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=5').then(ddd => ddd.json())
        .then(data => {


             setCom(data)

            setLoading(false)
        })
    })
    
    const coms = com.map(data => <h3>{data.body} <br/></h3>)

    if(isLoading){

        return <h1>Loading</h1>
    }
    else if(isLoading === false){
        return (

            <div className="con">
                {coms}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

so in this components I have two states one to store the comments and other to store a loading value that will change after it's done fetching the state in the `useEffect`.

The problem with this code is that let's say the server went down or my internet went out, even if it comes back this component is going to stay in the loading phase forever until the user refreshes the page manually. So how do I make the components re-fetch the data or rather just refresh the components ?.

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://swr.vercel.app/ solves the issue, without you writing a bunch of logic. The package is designed exactly for your use case.

Comment: You could put `setLoading` in a `finally` block instead of the `then` block... `fetch().then(setCom).finally(() => setLoading(false))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few improvements on how you can handle above logic.

```
    function App() {
      const [com, setCom] = useState([]);
      const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(false); //Set initial value to false to avoid your component in loading state if the first call fails
      const refreshTime = 2000 //How frequently you want to refresh the data, in ms
      
      const fetchComments = async () => {
        setisLoading(true) //set to true only when the api call is going to happen
        const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=5').then(ddd => ddd.json()).then(data => {
          if(Array.isArray(data)) setCom(data);
        })
        setisLoading(false); //make sure to set it to false so the component is not in constant loading state
      }
      
      useEffect(() => {
        const comInterval = setInterval(fetchComments, refreshTime); //This will refresh the data at regularIntervals of refreshTime
        return () => clearInterval(comInterval) //Clear interval on component unmount to avoid memory leak
      },[])
      
      const coms = com.map(data => <h3>{data.body} <br/></h3>)
      if(isLoading){

            return <h1>Loading</h1>
        }
        else if(isLoading === false){
            return (

                <div className="con">
                    {coms}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `setInterval()` to update the state with fetched data every second or however long is required. Here is an example:

```
const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState(/* data type */);
setInterval(() => setFetchedData(/* call to the method */), 1000);
```

This way, the component will fetch data every second and re-render the component.

Keep in mind though, this should ONLY be used if you know you are going to get an update every so often. If you are uselessly re-rendering and re-fetching data, that will be a constant hinderance towards performance.